# setInterval in a listener function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, setinterval

I have a listener function that trigger every seconds, you can think of it it's a video metadata function

```
video.on('media_info', function(data){
   //I want to get the speed and switch video quality, I can get the speed by accessing data.speed
})
```

How do I use setInterval here? I want to execute my logic every 2 minutes, not every seconds, I assume if I put this in the body I'll make the  setInterval trigger even more frequent

```
  const switchQuality = speed => {
    if(speed > 300) { switch to high quality }
    if(speed > 150) { switch to medium quality }
  };

  setInterval(() => switchQuality(speed), 120000);
```

Comment: do you mean the event `'media_info'` will be fired every second but you want `switchQuality` function to only run every 120 seconds?

Comment: @Solo how can I get the speed then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `media_info` event is triggered every second, why not simply add a counter variable and run your logic each time, the counter reaches 120 (or a number that's divisable by it without any rest)?

```
var counter = 0;

media.on('media_info', data => {
  counter += 1;
  if (counter % 120 === 0) {
    switchQuality(data.speed);
  }
});
```

Or:

```
var counter = 0;

media.on('media_info', data => {
  counter += 1;
  if (counter >= 120) {
    counter = 0;
    switchQuality(data.speed);
  }
});
```

Then there's no need to use either `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.

Comment: this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution. Just an idea:

```
setInterval(() => {
  video.once('media_info', function(data) {
    if(data.speed > 300) { switch to high quality }
    if(data.speed > 150) { switch to medium quality }
  })
});
```

If there is no one-time event listener you may create it.

What happens here: Every 120 secs you create an event listener. Next second it will give you speed and remove itself.